# create an NGINX location context to allow a partial URL to be expanded to a full URL

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

To access my app, you need to goto https://dev01.domain.com/dev01/admin/index.php

I am trying to configure nginx so that if the user types in any of the following, they will endup at the full URL I reference earlier...

```
https://dev01.domain.com/
https://dev01.domain.com/dev
https://dev01.domain.com/dev/
https://dev01.domain.com/dev/admin
https://dev01.domain.com/dev/admin/
```

After a ton of reading everything I can find plus a lot of playing around, I finally came up with this scenerio

```
server {
location = / {
        try_files $uri /dev01/admin/index.php;
}

location = /dev01 {
        try_files $uri /admin/index.php;
}


location = /dev01/ {
        try_files $uri admin/index.php;
}


location = /dev01/admin/ {
        try_files $uri /index.php;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri /dev01/admin/index.php =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
        }

}
```

Although this seems to produce the results I am looking for, I am thinking there is a better, more optimzed, way of handling this.

Any suggestions would be appreciated... Thank you

-----------------additional info------------------

I totally agree with your theory of how this should work.  I have played around with a lot of scenerios like this.   I have attached the key parts of my server {} context as well as the debug error log when i try to hit

http://dev.example.com

It seems we can see the attempt from $uri and $uri/, but then when they fail, I though it should go back to the "fallback" (the last param of try_files)
but instead it seems to try the non-existant index.html, then tries for a directory index of the root, and when that generates a 403, it internally redirects to my /error.html location.
It never seems to even attempt to hit the "fallback"... (/dev01/admin/index.php?$query_string)

```
server {

...

root /mnt/files;

location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /dev01/admin/index.php?$query_string;
}

error_page 403 /error.html;
location = /error.html {
    proxy_pass  http://example.com/redirect-error/;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri /dev01/admin/index.php =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
}

...
}
```

-- here are the debug log files the attempt creates

```
2018/08/09 11:53:40 [debug] 10318#0: *1 test location: "/"
2018/08/09 11:53:40 [debug] 10318#0: *1 test location: ~ "\.php$"
2018/08/09 11:53:40 [debug] 10318#0: *1 using configuration "/"
2018/08/09 11:53:40 [debug] 10318#0: *1 http cl:-1 max:1048576
2018/08/09 11:53:40 [debug] 10318#0: *1 rewrite phase: 3
2018/08/09 11:53:40 [debug] 10318#0: *1 post rewrite phase: 4
2018/08/09 11:53:40 [debug] 10318#0: *1 generic phase: 5
2018/08/09 11:53:40 [debug] 10318#0: *1 generic phase: 6
2018/08/09 11:53:40 [debug] 10318#0: *1 generic phase: 7
2018/08/09 11:53:40 [debug] 10318#0: *1 access phase: 8
2018/08/09 11:53:40 [debug] 10318#0: *1 access phase: 9
2018/08/09 11:53:40 [debug] 10318#0: *1 access phase: 10
2018/08/09 11:53:40 [debug] 10318#0: *1 post access phase: 11
2018/08/09 11:53:40 [debug] 10318#0: *1 generic phase: 12
2018/08/09 11:53:40 [debug] 10318#0: *1 try files handler
2018/08/09 11:53:40 [debug] 10318#0: *1 http script var: "/"
2018/08/09 11:53:40 [debug] 10318#0: *1 trying to use file: "/" "/mnt/files/"
2018/08/09 11:53:40 [debug] 10318#0: *1 http script var: "/"
2018/08/09 11:53:40 [debug] 10318#0: *1 trying to use dir: "/" "/mnt/files/"
2018/08/09 11:53:40 [debug] 10318#0: *1 try file uri: "/"
2018/08/09 11:53:40 [debug] 10318#0: *1 generic phase: 13
2018/08/09 11:53:40 [debug] 10318#0: *1 content phase: 14
2018/08/09 11:53:40 [debug] 10318#0: *1 open index "/mnt/files/index.html"
2018/08/09 11:53:40 [debug] 10318#0: *1 stat() "/mnt/files/index.html" failed (2: No such file or directory)
2018/08/09 11:53:40 [debug] 10318#0: *1 http index check dir: "/mnt/files"
2018/08/09 11:53:40 [debug] 10318#0: *1 content phase: 15
2018/08/09 11:53:40 [debug] 10318#0: *1 content phase: 16
2018/08/09 11:53:40 [debug] 10318#0: *1 content phase: 17
2018/08/09 11:53:40 [error] 10318#0: *1 directory index of "/mnt/files/" is forbidden, client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: dev.domain.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "dev.domain.com"
2018/08/09 11:53:40 [debug] 10318#0: *1 http finalize request: 403, "/?" a:1, c:1
2018/08/09 11:53:40 [debug] 10318#0: *1 http special response: 403, "/?"
2018/08/09 11:53:40 [debug] 10318#0: *1 internal redirect: "/error.html?"
```

Comment: Try removing `try_files` directive in `.php$` location block, and it's worth to add: `index index.php`; in `server` block.

Comment: same results ----

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
server {

location = / {
 rewrite "(?i)^/$" /dev01/admin/index.php permanent;
 rewrite "(?i)^/dev/?$" /dev01/admin/index.php permanent;
 rewrite "(?i)^/dev/admin/?$" /dev01/admin/index.php permanent;
}

location = /dev01/admin/ {
        try_files $uri /index.php;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri /dev01/admin/index.php =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd better (re)read the documentation on [location configuration](http://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html).

The following code should serve as an example of your usecase. The `try_files` part would depend on your `root` directive. More information [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files).

```
location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /dev01/admin/index.php?$query_string;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

Comment: I added more info the the main quesiton showing the results of this suggestion.